# Python. Есть несколько массивов "ключ-значение" (строка-строка). Надо собрать их в один массив

Tags: python

Есть такая задачка, долго ломал голову но решение найти так и не смог, вот её текст:
Есть несколько массивов "ключ-значение" (строка-строка). Надо собрать их в один массив, в котором:

1. общие ключи будут ровно один раз;
2. порядок строк будет максимально сохранен;
3. если возможно непротиворечивое сохранение порядка - этот результат должен быть получен;
4. если не возможно - принято любое разумное решение;
5. из всех возможных результатов предпочтителен (и должен быть найден!) результат с минимальной дистанцией строк от исходной.

Пример:
А)
Массив 1 (по ключам): a b c d
Массив 2 (по ключам): b d e
Результат: a b c d e

Б)
Массив 1 (по ключам): a b c d
Массив 2 (по ключам): b e d
Результат: a b c e d или a b e c d

В)
Массив 1 (по ключам): a d b
Массив 2 (по ключам): b e d
Результат: a d b e или a b e d

Г)
Массив 1 (по ключам): a b c d
Массив 2 (по ключам): a e f
Результат: a b e c f d или что-то похожее

Answer (score 1):

На этом сайте помогают тем, кто хоть пытается решить задачу самостоятельно. Приложите свои попытки -  и вам помогут их довести. А так - вы просто предлагаете нам решить ваше домашнее задание вместо вас.

Поэтому -  готового решения, которое вы потом выдадите за свое  -  не будет. Но вот подсказки - в какую сторону копать  -  дам.

1. Два массива объединяются в один, повторяющиеся элементы отбрасываются. Выполняется в одно действие, через использование множества. Если вы с таким понятием на знакомы -  ну так пишите цикл, который сравнивает поэлементно два списка и формирует третий, в который заносить элемент, если его еще в этом (результирующем" списке не было. Последний вариант сохраняет порядок элементов.
2. Аналогично. Тем более, что даже приведенные примеры желаемых ответов у вас совпадают.
   (Что вы имели ввиду, когда при одних входных данных приводите два возможных результата -  загадка. Закрадывается вопрос -  а вы вообще-то в курсе, что такое компьютерная программа?)
3. Если из вашего предыдущего примера убрать элемент "с", то чем пример 3 отличается от примера 2?
4. Чем пример 4 отличается от примера 1 (кроме конкретных букв, конечно).

И общий вопрос. Что такое "массивов "ключ-значение" (строка-строка)"?? В Python есть понятие "словарь". Тогда все сказанное выше можно отнести к ключам словаря. Если вы под этим термином понимаете что-то другое - то советую сначала прочитать какой-нибудь элементарный учебник по Python, что бы использовать всем понятную терминологию, потом перевести ваш вопрос на общепринятый язык. Да и вообще -  думаю, ознакомиться с инструментов надо до того, как пытаться им пользоваться.